# How to get remaining rows from table after remove()ing a row

Tags: jquery

I have some code that should remove the parent row of the clicked td and then return the id's of the other rows to an input box.  If I comment out the remove line it all works well, but with the remove call I get an error:

```
rows is undefined
 for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) { 

$("td.remove").live('click', function(event) {
    var element  = this;

    $(this).parent().remove();

    var rows  = $(element).parents('table').attr("rows");

    answer = '';                       
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        answer += rows[i].id+",";
    }

    $('#' + $(this).parents('table').attr("title")).val(answer);

});
```

How can I get the remaining rows after I have deleted the row I clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the parent element, its descendent elements will not exist.

You'll need to refactor your code so you have a reference to the outer `table` without relying on deleted elements.

Comment: ok, thanks.  That pointed me in the right direction.  what was tricking me was that when i was setting a variable to the table and then removing the row, the var with the table ref wasn't being updated.  So, instead i set a var to the id, and then worked on the table after i removed the row.

Comment: $("td.remove").live('click', function(event) {
 var element  = this;
 
 var table  = $(this).parents('table').attr("id");
 
 
 $(this).parent().remove();
 
 var rows  = $('#'+table).attr("rows");
 
  
   answer = '';                       
 for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
     answer += rows[i].id+",";
 }
  
 inputId = $('#'+table).attr("title");
 $('#'+inputId).val(answer);
  
});